# How do I let randomized colors differ by 40° per phase to all other stimuli in R?

Tags: r, colors

I want to create a stimulus list for a study. This will show at most 5 stimuli in a single phase with randomized colors. These color should differ by atleast 40° to all other stimuli in the phase. Furhter they need to differ atleast +-40° from a predefined number. I manged to code it in a way that they differ the +-40° from the set color but not to each other. They will always differ 40° from the prvevious stimuli but no from all in the phase.
This is my R Code

```
min_distance      <- 40 # minimal distance between colors in degrees (max distance is twice min distance)

n_cols <- n_colors(load)
  
  for (i in 1:2) {
    
    hues_all <- temp_all %>%
      pivot_wider(id_cols = trial_number, names_from = trial_seq, values_from = hue) %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(hue = random_colors(n_cols, min_distance)) %>%
      separate(hue, paste("hue", 0:n_cols, sep = "_"), extra = "drop", sep = "\\D+") %>%
      discard(~all(is.na(.) | . == "")) %>%
      #select(starts_with("hue")) %>%
      type_convert()
    
    names <- c(paste("hue", 0:(n_cols-1), sep = "_"), "trial_number")
    
    hues_all <- hues_all %>%
      relocate(sample(2:ncol(.))) %>%
      set_names(., names) %>%
      add_count(hue_0) %>%
      arrange(-n, -hue_0)
    
    hues_remaining <- hues_all
    
    hues_prm <- hues_all %>%
      head(n = nrow(stim_prm))
    
#    if(nrow(hues_prm) > hues_all$n[1]) {
#      stop("Error: NOT ENOUGH identical colors for the number of prospectice memory cues")
#    }
    
    hues_remaining <- hues_all %>%
      slice(which(! hues_remaining$trial_number %in% hues_prm$trial_number))
    
    hues_prm <- hues_prm %>%
      select(-n) %>%
      pivot_longer(!hue_0 & !trial_number, names_to = "trial_seq", values_to = "hue") %>%
      mutate(abs_color_dev = abs(color_dev_deg(hue_0, hue))) %>%
      #separate(trial_seq, c("drop", "trial_seq")) %>%
      #select(-drop) %>%
      type_convert()
    
    hues_filler <- hues_prm
    
    hues_prm <- hues_prm %>%
      group_by(trial_number) %>%
      mutate(max_color_dev = max(abs_color_dev)) %>%
      filter(abs_color_dev == max_color_dev) %>%
      rename(hue_prom = hue_0, trial_number_hues = trial_number) %>%
      select(hue, hue_prom, abs_color_dev) %>%
      mutate(trial_type = "prom", stimulus_type = "prom_spec") %>%
      bind_cols(prm_positions) %>%
      add_column(trial_seq = median(1:current_load)-0.5) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      select(trial_seq, trial_number, trial_type, stimulus_type, hue, hue_prom,
             abs_color_dev)
    
    hues_filler <- hues_filler %>%
      slice(which(! hues_filler$hue %in% hues_prm$hue)) %>%
      select(trial_number, trial_seq, hue) %>%
      group_by(trial_number) %>%
      mutate(hue = sample(hue, replace = FALSE)) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = trial_seq, values_from = hue) %>%
      rename(trial_number_hues = trial_number) %>%
      mutate(trial_type = "prom", stimulus_type = "ongoing") %>%
      bind_cols(prm_positions) %>%
      select(-trial_number_hues) %>%
      pivot_longer(!trial_type & !stimulus_type & !block_number & !trial_number &
                     !trial_number_hues, names_to = "trial_seq", values_to = "hue",
                   names_prefix = "hue_") %>%
      type_convert() %>%
      ungroup()
    
    hues_filler <- hues_filler %>%
      mutate(trial_seq = rep(1:(max(load)-1), nrow(hues_filler)/(max(load)-1) )) %>%
      filter(trial_seq < current_load) %>%
      select(trial_seq, trial_number, trial_type, stimulus_type, hue)
    
    hues_remaining <- hues_remaining %>%
      arrange(trial_number) %>%
      select(-hue_0, -n) %>%
      pivot_longer(!trial_number, names_to = "trial_seq", values_to = "hue",
                   names_prefix = "hue_") %>%
      type_convert() %>%
      group_by(trial_number) %>%
      mutate(hue = sample(hue, replace = FALSE)) %>%
      add_column(trial_type = "ongoing", stimulus_type = "ongoing") %>%
      filter(trial_seq <= current_load) %>%
      ungroup()
    
    hues_remaining <- hues_remaining %>%
      mutate(trial_number = rep(1:(nrow(hues_remaining)/current_load), each = current_load))
    
    hues_pra <- hues_remaining %>%
      slice_tail(n = n_practice_stimuli) %>%
      mutate(trial_type = "practice",
             trial_number = rep(1:(n_practice_stimuli/current_load), each = current_load))
    
    hues_remaining <- hues_remaining %>%
      slice(which(! hues_remaining$trial_number %in% hues_pra$trial_number))
    
    hues_remaining <- hues_remaining %>%
      mutate(trial_number = rep(1:(nrow(hues_remaining)/current_load), each = current_load))
    
    temp_all_hues <- hues_prm %>%
      select(trial_seq, trial_number, trial_type, stimulus_type, hue, hue_prom) %>%
      bind_rows(hues_filler, hues_remaining) %>%
      arrange(trial_number, trial_seq)
    
    temp_all_hues <- bind_rows(hues_pra, temp_all_hues)
    
    temp_all_hues <- temp_all_hues %>%
      mutate(stimulus_seq = 1:nrow(temp_all_hues),
             trial_seq = rep(1:current_load, nrow(temp_all_hues)/current_load),
             trial_number = rep(1:(nrow(temp_all_hues)/current_load), each = current_load))
    
    temp_all_hues$hue      <- temp_all_hues$hue -179
    temp_all_hues$hue_prom <- temp_all_hues$hue_prom -179
    
    names(temp_all_hues)[names(temp_all_hues) == "hue"] <- paste0("hue_v", i)
    names(temp_all_hues)[names(temp_all_hues) == "hue_prom"] <- paste0("hue_prom_v", i)
    
    if (exists("tmp")) {
      temp_all_hues <- full_join(tmp, temp_all_hues,
                                 by = c("trial_number", "trial_seq", "trial_type",
                                        "stimulus_type", "stimulus_seq"))
    }
    
    tmp <- temp_all_hues
    #assign(paste0("hues_prm_v", i), hues_prm)
    
  }
```

Code

hue_prm are the preset color that everything need to differ atleast +-40° from

Any ideas? Tried a lot. This is just the color part of the code

I tried playing around with the min_distance as well as the some of the mutate lines and the slicing